# Entire computer is broken after installing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios

I had ubuntu 17.04, and I had wifi problems with it, so I reinstalled 16.04, and now whenever I boot my computer, I get a boot screen that says

```
boot menu                     App Menu
1. ubuntu                     Setup
2. USB HDD:                   Diagnostic Splash
3. Windows Boot Manager
```

If I enter anything, it just reloads to this screen.

I can't boot into windows or ubuntu.  Please Help as I need to go to work, and this computer is what I use to work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a live Ubuntu flash drive, and use boot-repair. You can get more in-depth instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Basically, you have to run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

then follow the instructions it gives you after pressing `Recommended Repair`.

Comment: When I click Try Ubuntu, I get `softreset failed (device not ready)`

Comment: Use another computer to make a live ubuntu flash drive. Then boot from it and not the hard drive.

Comment: I tried that.  It just goes to the same screen.

Comment: If you can't boot from a live USB drive, try a live CD

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu then it's the exact some thing, booting from the USB. If you're having issues then you may have started with problematic installation/live media. I suggest you make a proper one and reinstall. 16.04 wil NOT solve any WiFi issue you're having with a newer release.